# Parse xml with same properties but different parent elements using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to parse some xml provided by a separate service. They provide this xml as different elements but I treat them the same. I.E.

```
<ElementA>
 <name>foo</name>
 <type>bar</type>
</ElementA>


<ElementB>
 <name>foo1</name>
 <type>bar1</type>
</ElementB>
```

This is how in the data but when I parse/unmarshall it with JAXB I want it to know that ElementA and ElementB are both just instances of the Element class and unmarshall it as such. Currently I am doing this by using the XmlRegistry to say that ElementA is an Element and ElementB is an Element.

However at some point we might receive ElementC and ElementD so I would like a way for JAXB to know those are also just Element without having to add an entry to the XmlRegistry everytime.

Comment: How would you describe it in an xsd?

Comment: I don't really know, basically parent/root element can be anything and then it has known properties, name, type etc. I suppose if i knew how to write an xsd for it it would solve my problems.